# Getting properties from classes within classes in a generic function

Tags: c#, list, generics, properties

This question is a follow-up based on an earlier question:
[Use a generic method with a list of different type/class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28281229/use-a-generic-method-with-a-list-of-different-type-class)

I have the following generic function which looks up properties and sort the list based on the property that has been given as a parameter:

```
public static void SortList<T>(ref List<T> list, String sortExpression, SortDirection sortDirection) { 
    IList<PropertyInfo> properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
    foreach(var prop in properties){
        if(prop.Name.Equals(sortExpression)){
            if (sortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending) {
                list.Sort(delegate(T t1, T t2) { return prop.GetValue(t1).ToString().CompareTo(prop.GetValue(t2).ToString()); });
            } else {
                list.Sort(delegate(T t1, T t2) { return prop.GetValue(t2).ToString().CompareTo(prop.GetValue(t1).ToString()); });
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

This searches all properties of a class and sorts the list based on that property. However, if I have for example a class uitlening which looks as follows:

```
public class Uitlening {
    public Int64 id { get; set; }
    public Exemplaar exemplaar { get; set; }
    public Medewerker medewerker { get; set; }
    public String van { get; set; }
    public String tot { get; set; }
}
```

It contains two sub-classes, Exemplaar and Medewerker. My function as is only loops through the properties from Uitlening and not through the properties of Exemplaar and Medewerker.

How can I get the 'sub-properties' from the sub-classes to loop through it and sort my list also based on them?

**(I'd like to keep my function generic and not put any class related terms in it; I.E.**

```
if(prop.Name.Equals("Exemplaar") )
```

Comment: Why are you looping through all properties just to find one? `typeof(T).GetProperty(sortExpression)` will do it without the loop

Comment: That's a good addition, however it still cannot seem to find the sub properties.

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use reflection instead of Linq's `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending` functions? Either way, you could split `sortExpression` on dots and apply some recursion to get the final value you need to sort it.

Comment: What would `sortExpression` look like if you were wanting to sort by subproperties? `exemplaar.subproperty` perhaps? In which case all you need to do is split by the period (`.`) and keep calling `GetProperty` until you find it

Comment: The particular reason why I ask this, is that I also want to learn how to use reflection and its functions. Furthermore I use gridview Headers to sort on click, so I do not know in advance which property has to be ordered on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried many things and created the following generic method to also sort on subclasses:

```
    public static void SortList<T>(ref List<T> list, String sortExpression, SortDirection sortDirection) {
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(sortExpression);
        if (propertyInfo != null) {
            if (sortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending) {
                list.Sort(delegate(T t1, T t2) { return propertyInfo.GetValue(t1).ToString().CompareTo(propertyInfo.GetValue(t2).ToString()); });
            } else {
                list.Sort(delegate(T t1, T t2) { return propertyInfo.GetValue(t2).ToString().CompareTo(propertyInfo.GetValue(t1).ToString()); });
            }
            return;
        } else {
            foreach (var props in typeof(T).GetProperties()) {
                PropertyInfo pro = props.PropertyType.GetProperty(sortExpression);
                if (pro != null) {
                    if (pro.Name.Equals(sortExpression)) {
                        if (sortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending) {
                            list.Sort(delegate(T t1, T t2) {
                                return pro.GetValue(props.GetValue(t1)).ToString().CompareTo(pro.GetValue(props.GetValue(t2)).ToString());
                            });
                        } else {
                            list.Sort(delegate(T t1, T t2) {
                                return pro.GetValue(props.GetValue(t2)).ToString().CompareTo(pro.GetValue(props.GetValue(t1)).ToString());
                            });
                        }
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It basically returns when a hit is found, so no unnecessary time is used. First it looks on the first class hierarchy, thereafter it will look on the second hierarchy. (Of course it is now simple to expand to further hierarchy's)
I share the answer, for if anybody else might be interested in the answer or anyone has some additional feedback.

Comment: You can clean things up by moving the actual sorting code into a helper function. There's no need for the `pro.Name.Equals(sortExpression)` - `GetProperty(sortExpression)` already returns a property with that name, or null otherwise. If you want to support searching multiple levels you may want to write a recursive function, but in that case you'll need to take cyclic properties into account (`A.B` and `B.A` pointing to each other, or `A.A` pointing to itself) or just pass in a maximum search depth.

Comment: Thank you, I did remove the Name.Equals from the first hierarchy, forgot it from the second.

A cyclic function would indeed do the job and is much more efficiënt than typing out each and every hierarchy. However, for my application I need only 1 sub hierarchy, so I am going with this. If I have time later on I will definitely try to create a cyclic function. (Just out of curiosity)

Comment: A function that calls itself is called 'recursive', not cyclic. An object that references itself (directly or indirectly) is said to have a 'circular reference' - you could say it's part of a 'cyclic object graph'. It's useful to know the common name(s) for something when you need to search for it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a recursive method that looks at properties, then properties of properties and so on down through the object graph. When it hits on the given property name, it stops recursing and returns the ToString() of the matched property's value.

Then do the sort.

What you are trying to achieve has a potential danger though: you may get an  unexpected hit, so though you are trying to make a solution that will work on anything, to be sure it works you need some prior knowledge of the names of the properties all the way down, which means it doesn't really do what you want.

You could tell your recursive method to only recurse on properties of certain types provided in an argument, or those that implement a given interface or inherit from a given base class. In cases where you are sure that you won't get any false positives (on name alone) you could default to object.